# Custom Web part with filter that doesn't cause postback

Tags: javascript, client-side-rendering

I have a custom Content Query Web Part that currently pulls in events into a custom calendar, by month, with selectable filters that filter event listed on the calendar by a field value on the Event type. I would like to be able to change the month, without causing a postback as that clears out the selected filters. Is there a way to do this? I am using client side rending for the custom page template (jslink).